# Run android application (ionic cordova) error "unable to find valid certification path to the requested target"

Tags: java, android, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm not very familiar with js technologies and I'm working on a Typescript project (with ionic cordova) for android. I've retrieved this project from a colleague. The project works on its environment.

My configuration:

- Visual Studio Code 1.30 for Windows 64
- Android SDK 28
- Ionic cli 4.8.0
- Cordova 8.1.2
- Java 8
- right env vars JRE_HOME and ANDROID_SDK

I ran the following commands in Visual Studio Code

1. "npm i" the first time
2. ionic cordova build android

The second triggers the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
...
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145) 
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131) 
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
```

Moreover, when I start "ionic serve", a localhost page is opened on my browser. First the webapp is displayed one second, and then an error page is displayed:

"Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available"

With the following stack:

```
c@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752 
c@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19461 
f/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20233 F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15649 onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5436:24
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15562 
F</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10815 
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7887
```

And the following informations:

- Ionic Framework 3.9.2
- Ionic App Scripts 3.2.1
- Angular Core 5.2.11
- Angular Compiler CLI 5.2.11

I don't know what is wrong, particularly when the project works on the pc of my colleague. So I assume I don't have anything to do in the project configuration files.

Now it's working on "ionic cordova build browser" but not "ionic cordova build android" (android is defined as a platform in package.json).

I don't have any idea of what to do. Have you any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after some days I've found the problem was the installed JRE.
I uninstalled my current JRE 8 and installed another version and it's work fine.

However, I don't understand why but it's ok now.